# Why are the two resistors in parallel? They are next to each other, so they should be in series, right?

Tags: resistors, parallel, series

Why are the two resistors in parallel? They are next to each other, so they should be in series, right?

[image]

Comment: Right. Who said they are in parallel?

Comment: unless you are calculating output impedance, in which case you consider the voltage source as a short and now they are in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends from where you are looking into the circuit:

1.) As seen from the voltage source Vo both resistors are - of course - in series.

2.) However, when looking into the circuit from the node A the internal resistance is (R3 + R1||R2).

In general: Asking for a total resistance of a circuit we always must give the information from where we look into the circuit (at which point we would connect a test current source for measuring the total resistance).

Answer (score 3):

> *Why are the two resistors in parallel? They are next to each other, so
> they should be in series, right?*

Strictly speaking they are neither in series nor in parallel because of the R3 connection.